# File Upload Browser details

Tags: nautilus

Is there a way to get details of file upload popup like what thread/process id responsible for opening it ? I tried getting data out of default file manager of Ubuntu ......nautilus. Basically i want to in depth detail of how file browser opens and what process works at the backend ?

[image]

xporp output is as follow:-

```
_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 5, 147, 54, 54
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 28, 0
_BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE(STRING) = "/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop"
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_MODAL, _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        Initial state is Normal State.
        window id # of group leader: 0x3200001
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_GTK_MENUBAR_OBJECT_PATH(UTF8_STRING) = "/com/canonical/unity/gtk/window/61"
_UNITY_OBJECT_PATH(UTF8_STRING) = "/com/canonical/unity/gtk/window/61"
_GTK_UNIQUE_BUS_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = ":1.64"
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 910, 619
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "GtkFileChooserDialog"
WM_TRANSIENT_FOR(WINDOW): window id # 0x320001d
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 52451828, 52451829
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 12154881
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x32059f3
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x3200001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 2028
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "ubuntu"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified location: 0, 0
        program specified minimum size: 534 by 356
        program specified base size: 0 by 0
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "firefox", "Firefox"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "File Upload"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "File Upload"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "File Upload"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "File Upload"
```

Comment: Run the command `xprop` and then click on the window

Comment: Oh..it gives the process id of firefox.....why doesn't it have some thread/process it of its own.also is there a way to get this data through script instead of me clicking on windows